# How do I run a batch script from within a batch script using powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-3.0

How do I call another batch script from within a batch script in powershell. In bash I used to get this done using the CALL keyword. Is there an equivalent term for that in powershell ??

My problem is basically to start a dev environment using a batch file and then run some commands in that environment with the second batch file.

I tried using something like

```
& Path\to\my\batchfile.bat -/c'command with spaces'
```

I was expecting it to open the dev environment with the batch file and run the provided command but it just keep runs the batch file and does not run the commands in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *assuming* that your use case is as follows:

- You want to run batch file `B.bat`,
- but batch file `A.bat` must run *first*, to set the environment that `B.bat` relies on.

```
# "foo" and "bar" are sample arguments for B.bat
cmd /c 'c:\path\to\A.bat && c:\path\to\B.bat foo bar'
```

Note:

- The `call` batch-file command is *not* needed in this case; `call` is only needed *inside* a batch file to call *another* batch file in a manner that returns control to the calling batch file.
- As long as `A.bat` sets its variables *without using `setlocal`*, `B.bat` will see those (environment) variables too.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

If `A.bat` *does* use `setlocal` - which limits the scope of variable definitions to that batch file<sup>[1]</sup> - and *you're unable to modify `A.bat`* to remove this constraint, there is *no* solution to your problem - irrespective of whether you call from `cmd.exe` or PowerShell. (That is, *unless* `A.bat` happens to be designed to accept a command line to execute *as an argument*.)

---

<sup>[1] Unlike in PowerShell, in `cmd.exe` *all* variables are *environment* variables. However, the optional `setlocal` command allows you to scope such variables to a given batch file (and, when paired with `endlocal` calls, even to *parts* of a batch file). For help, run `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` from `cmd.exe`.</sup>

Comment: This partially works, I get to set the environment with the first batch file but then I need it stop and run the second batch file. Problem is this only runs them in sequence. Can I stop the first file to exit and start the second files execution. Other wise my commands in second file are not getting recognized.

Comment: @chad_90, running them _in sequence_ is the prerequisite for the use case I describe. Whatever environment variables are set in `A.bat` _are_ seen by `B.bat` - unless you accidentally used `setlocal` in `A.bat`

Comment: yes the first file only sets the environment locally so I would need the second file to work within the same session.  I cannot modify the first A.bat file as well.